# use git-svn to keep svn history

Tags: git, svn, version-control

The remote central repository is based on SVN. As I want to use GIT, the only thing I can touch is using git-svn bridge to clone the target svn project like "git svn clone http://svn/repos/a/trunnk" where the project name is "a".

In svn, when I use "svn copy" or "svn move" it will copy the file history, but in git-svn, it seems there is no way to do the same thing to keep the history?

Answer (score 0):

> In svn, when I use "svn copy" or "svn move" it will copy the file history, but in git-svn, it seems there is no way to do the same thing to keep the history?

you want to push the changes of your local git-svn clone back to the server?

thats done with
    git svn dcommit

if thats not what u were looking for try asking the question more precisely